# Component initialization with Iron Router, Jquery, Materialize

Tags: meteor, iron-router, materialize

Struggling here with what would otherwise be a simple `$( document ).ready()`.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Materialize needs jquery components to be initialized on *DOM ready*. Finding a way to initialize components on all views is surprisingly tricky.

**Here** is the online [DEMO](http://meteortabsissue.meteor.com)

From reading the docs: this should initialize everything the sub-templates require:

```
Template.layout.rendered = function(){ 

  $('ul.tabs').tabs() 

  }
}
```

However, this only works on a hard page refresh, and not with links routing the views.

So instead you would have to initialize on each template that element will be used

```
Template.x.rendered ...

Template.y.rendered ...
```

**Here** is the [github code](https://github.com/keyscores/meteortabsissue/)

BTW We've tried iron-router events:

```
onRun

onBeforeAction

onAfterAction
```

All of these seem to happen before the route's template content is present. I noticed that onBeforeAction required a call to `this.next()` to go on, I even tried looking for the DOM content after the next call.

I also tried rewriting our routes like this:

```
Router.route('someRoute', function() {
  this.render('someRoute');
  // look for DOM content, still not found
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the cleanup Ethaan

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, the reason this is happening is because your layout is only firing the rendered hook once. When you switch routes the layout template will not be rerendered, only the templates in the yield region will be. The previous template in that region gets destroyed and the next one rerendered. This means you have to run `$('ul.tabs').tabs()` again for that Template as the DOM elements it contains are rerendered.

Putting that code in the rendered function of the template that uses it works because that rendered hook gets run every time that particular template gets rendered again.

A way you could get around this could be to create a Template specifically for your tabs, like a control in a way, that calls `$('ul.tabs').tabs()` in its own rendered function. You could then put this control on a template that needed it and pass the required arguments, like number of tabs and content for each tab etc. It's a bit of work though, and I'd only consider it if I had a really large number of templates that used the tab control.

Comment: Hi Jon thanks for this, but there must be a way in meteor to have a script be initialized on a generic template. I thought that was what body.rendered was intended for. Any thoughts?

Comment: I've been trying to get the `materialbox` image to work and since I've added iron router, it only works the time it's clicked and won't work again until I refresh the page. I have put the initialisation code in the `onRendered` of a template that is in my yield which is what you have said should work if I've undersood you correctly. Any thoughts on this?